# CSS flexbox horizontal masonry: place one more item than fits/negative space between

Tags: css, flexbox

This might be a bit hard to explain. Let's start with an example:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.iw {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/325x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/175x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/175x150"></div>
  <div class="iw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225x150"></div>
</div>
```

This is how it renders on my screen:

[image]

See how there's gaps between the items? I want to remove that gap entirely by shifting one extra item to the row above. e.g. move Box A to the end of Row 1.

Then, because I've set `overflow: hidden` and `text-align: center` on `.iw`, I want the left and right edges of each image to be chopped off a little bit so that everything fits perfectly snug in the row.

How can I achieve this effect?

---

By setting `min-width` on each of the containers to something like 50% of the image's width, I can get somewhat close to the effect I'm looking for:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.iw {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

.iw>* {
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
  right: -99999px;
  bottom: -99999px;
  left: -99999px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:175px;max-width:350px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/00f"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:75px;max-width:150px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/0f0"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:125px;max-width:250px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150/0ff"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:162.5px;max-width:325px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/325x150/f00"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:87.5px;max-width:175px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/175x150/f0f"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:125px;max-width:250px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150/ff0"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:150px;max-width:300px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150/00f"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:87.5px;max-width:175px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/175x150/0f0"></div>
  <div class="iw" style="min-width:112.5px;max-width:225px"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/225x150/0ff"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Except they can get a bit spaced depending on your browser width, which is no good. Also, they aren't properly centered in their divs -- both the left and right side should be chopped, not just the right.

---

You can see it's very close to working: https://i.imgur.com/lV5A210.gifv

But the team-fortress-girls pic should have been the last one on the row. You can see how it squishes the other images to make room, but then the next pic should have started on the next row. Instead, they all squish down to 50% (min-width) before it forces the next pic onto the 2nd row.

Comment: I have a bit consideration in your question. How does *shifting one extra item to the row above* remove the gap?

Comment: @Duannx "Box A" cannot fit in "Row 1", right? There's not enough horizontal space without it flowing over the right side of the page. What I want to do is squish all the `.iw` divs down a bit to make room (proportional to the size of their content). This will cause each of the images to overflow their respective container, but because I put `overflow: hidden` the edges will just be chopped off.

Comment: Do you want to use bit javascript or just pure css?

Comment: @Duannx I'd prefer CSS, but I'm not opposed to JS if that's the only way. I just don't want to kill my page performance by listening for resize events and trying to stuff all these things into row-divs.

Comment: I agree. I always use pure css as much as possible. But in this situation, i think pure css can not do the job. If you satisfied with `min-width` way. Just add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center;` to `.iw`. It will center the image.

Comment: @Duannx It's sooo close to working the way I want :-( https://i.imgur.com/lV5A210.gifv